# Program to find the Greatest and the Lowest value and it's index of an Array (C programming)

Tags: c, arrays

Part of the code to find the Greatest and the Lowest number on an array,if that is needed.
I need the index now. The position of those number in that array.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DIM 5

void lerArray (int x[DIM]);
int maximo(int x[DIM]);
int minimo(int x[DIM]);


int main(){
    int a[DIM],l,g;
    lerArray(a);
    g = maximo(a);
    l = minimo(a);

    printf("Minimo:%d \t  Maximo:%d ",g,l);


    return 0;
}


void lerArray (int x[DIM]){
    int i,numb;

    for(i=0;i<DIM;i++)
    {
        printf("Intoduza o %dº elemento\n",i);
            scanf("%d",&numb);
            x[i]= numb;
    }
}


int maximo(int x[DIM]){
    int i,max;
    max =x[0];

    for(i=0;i<DIM;i++){
        if (max>x[i])
            max = x[i];
    }
    return max;
}

int minimo(int x[DIM]){
    int i,min;
    min =x[0];

    for(i=0;i<DIM;i++){
        if(min<x[i])
             min=x[i];
    }

    return min;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the array index of the maximum value, return that instead of the max value. Then the calling function can easily print the value itself, if needed, by using the index. Incidentally, you have your comparisons the wrong way round.

```
int maximo(int x[DIM]){
    int i, max, maxind;
    max =x[0];
    maxind = 0;               // added this

    for(i=0;i<DIM;i++) {
        if (max < x[i]) {     // reversed the conditional test
            max = x[i];
            maxind = i;       // remember this too
        }
    }
    return maxind;            // return the index instead of the value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve the value and the index of the maximum/minimum value in your array, you need to save the last index `i` from which you changed the value of the maximum/minimum value in your functions.

In C you cannot return multiple values in a function.

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

One solution would be to give a pointer to an integer to your functions as an additional argument, in which you would store the index of the value.

Another solution would be to create a simple array of size 2 to store your result (min/max value) and the associated index, and use it as a parameter to your `maximo` and `minimo` function calls.

Or you could even create a structure containing both your result and it's index.